# Javascript Tile Map Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to programm a tile map with just 1 picture. It shall be a 5x5 field of small pictures. I have wrote some Javascript Code with 2 nested Loops. With this solution, only 1 pictures is printed. When i remove the br Tag in the second loop, 5 pictures are printed, but only in a row, not among themselves. Whats the problem? How can i realize that?

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('button_generateField').addEventListener('click', function generateField (spacefields) {

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

    var horizontal_field = new Image();
    horizontal_field.src = 'Grafiken/spacefields.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(horizontal_field);


    for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j++){

        var vertical_field = new Image();
        vertical_field.src = '/Grafiken/spacefieldsd.jpg';
        document.body.appendChild( '<br>' + vertical_field);

};


};

});}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<img src="testbanner1.jpg" alt="banner" width="1500" height="150px" >
</div>

<div id="main">

<button id="button_generateField">Generate Field!</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using the same variable name `i` on the inner and outer loop.  By the time the inner loop ends, the outer loop no longer meets the condition to continue (as `i` is now greater than 4) - Use a different variable name for the inner loop (I'd suggest `j`) and see how that goes

Comment: Oh you are right, don't see. I have changed that, but the problem is still the same. It just prints 1 picture by 1 Click at the Button.

Comment: can you add the HTML you are using to your question?

Comment: Its just a very simple HTML construct.

Comment: is `/Grafiken/spacefieldsd.jpg` a typo ?

Comment: try `document.createElement("img")` instead of `new Image()`

Comment: you only need to load the image once, then to tile it there is multiple methods. have you tried using css with background-image and background-repeat ?

Comment: your <br> will not work, you need to document.createElement("br")

Comment: Its just a typo for the english stackoverflow version. I use german filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Grafiken/spacefieldsd.jpg` looks like a typo.
use `document.createElement("img")` instead of `new Image()`.
your `<br>` will not work, you need to `document.createElement("br")`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button_generateField");
var div = document.getElementById("main");

var rows = 4;
  var cols = 4;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  for(y=0;y<rows;y++){
    
    for(x=0;x<cols;x++){
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100";
      img.onload = function(){

          

      }
      div.appendChild(img);
    }
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="button_generateField">Generate Field!</button>
<div id="main">

</div>
```